# Github clone: Fatal Error "cannot create directory at" (Windows)

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone a repo from Github that is working perfectly fine on MacOS, but Windows is throwing me an error:

```
Cloning into 'Explr'...
remote: Counting objects: 1936, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1461/1461), done.
remote: Total 1936 (delta 368), reused 1884 (delta 338), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1936/1936), 53.11 MiB | 2.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (368/368), done.
fatal: cannot create directory at 'App/Flutter/explr/build\ios': No such file or directory
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

It's not just the ios folder that is missing, more files are missing. But that could also be caused by this error I guess.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody has checked in a file with a backslash (`build\ios`) which is not a permissible filename on Windows, since it contains the directory separator.

You will not be able to checkout the entire repository on Windows unless you - or someone else - removes this file.